# $H_n(X,A)=0$ when $X$ is a CW complex of dimension smaller than $n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

It is well known that $H_n(X)=0$ when $X$ is a CW complex of dimension smaller than $n$. But I wonder if it is still true when we replace $X$ with a CW pair $(X,A)$.

When I try to prove this, the result doesn't seem to follow directly from the long exact sequence for $(X,A)$.

Comment: This should be true since we'll have $H_n(X, A) \cong H_n(X/A)$, and $X/A$ will certainly have dimension $< n$. There's probably a way to do this with just the long exact sequence of the pair, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result in fact does not follow from the long exact sequence for a pair, in the following sense: it is possible to write down spaces $A \subseteq X$ such that $A$ and $X$ have homological dimension less than $n$ (meaning their homology vanishes in degree $n$ above) but $X/A$ has homological dimension $n$. A simple example is to take $X = D^2, A = S^1$, which have homological dimensions $0$ and $1$ respectively, but $X/A \cong S^2$ has homological dimension $2$.

You can instead do it using the fact that $X/A$ is also a CW complex of dimension less than $n$, as Pedro says in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused about your first paragraph. Could you please clarify your definition of homological dimension? Is it simply the first number $n$ such that $\tilde{H}_n \ne 0$?

Comment: @Ti: a space has homological dimension $n$ if $H_n \neq 0$ (I don't want reduced homology here so that the case $n = 0$ works out correctly) but $H_m = 0$ for all $m \ge n+1$. For example, a closed orientable $n$-manifold has homological dimension $n$.

Comment: How do you show that $X/A$ is also a CW complex of dimension less than $n$?